# Using the API, is it possible to get the name of the user who created an activity record?

Tags: soql, api, activities, contracts

I have a SOQL query similar to the following:

```
SELECT Id, ContractNumber FROM Contract,
(SELECT Id, WhoId, WhatId, ActivityDate FROM ActivityHistories)
FROM Contract
```

Is it possible to get the name of the Salesforce user that created the activity record?  Or am I going to be required to fetch a full list of users and do the mapping in my server-side code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely.

```
 [SELECT Id, ContractNumber,  
 (SELECT Id, WhoId, WhatId, ActivityDate, createdby.name FROM ActivityHistories) 
 FROM Contract];
```

Fields on related objects (objects that you have a lookup to) can be referenced via dot notation in soql. You can find more information about this [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp):

> Client applications need to be able to query for more than a single
>   type of object at a time. SOQL provides syntax to support these types
>   of queries, called relationship queries, against both standard objects
>   and custom objects.
>
> Relationship queries traverse parent-to-child and child-to-parent
>   relationships between objects to filter and return results. They are
>   similar to SQL joins. However, you cannot perform arbitrary SQL joins.
>   The relationship queries in SOQL must traverse a valid relationship
>   path as defined in the rest of this section.
>
> You can use relationship queries to return objects of one type based
>   on criteria that applies to objects of another type, for example,
>   “return all accounts created by Bob Jones and the contacts associated
>   with those accounts.” There must be a parent-to-child or
>   child-to-parent relationship connecting the objects. You can’t write
>   arbitrary queries such as “return all accounts and users created by
>   Bob Jones.”

Answer (score 3):

The user who created the record would be stored in the CreatedById lookup. As it's a standard lookup the syntax for retrieving a field (name as an example) from the related object would be CreatedBy.name.

So you could pull this by modifying your query to:

```
SELECT Id, ContractNumber, 
(SELECT Id, WhoId, WhatId, ActivityDate, CreatedBy.name FROM ActivityHistories)
FROM Contract
```